# 2012 Sonata GLS won't turn on

Tags: hyundai, security, sonata

I disconnected the battery to reset a check engine code, after connecting the battery to start the car the car won't start. The interior lights including the hazard light keep flashing for about 15 sec, stop for 5 and restart flashing. I read several forum that stated that the battery would most likely the cause of the problem. I connected a jump start to the battery to verify if the battery could had gone bad, but even with the jump start the same issue occurred. I tried disconnecting the battery and turning on the highlights to completely drain the charge to reset the computer. This had no effect on the issue. Please advice if you may have any idea to remediate this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: almost sounds like a security issue. any flashing security lights when the key is in the on position? try locking and unlocking the car with the fob or lock unlock the car from the driver or passenger door a few times.

Comment: I tried locking and unlocking the car but it didn't make a difference. I'm under the impression that it's the security system but don't know how to reset it.